# Derive Poisson equation starting from Coulomb's law for a set of point charges

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, gauss-law, coulombs-law

Would that be correct, if we first find Gauss' law from Coulomb's law and then derive Poisson's equation using Gauss' law? Or is there any other method to directly obtain Poisson's equation from Coulomb's law?

Comment: The standard way I'd say would be to simply derive Gauss's law as you said, and then use the definition of the electric field from the potential.

Comment: It is not clear whether OP is asking about the correctness of the method or also *how* to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{q_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be point charges and $\vec{r}_i$ the corresponding position vectors.
According to the superposition principle, the total electric field is
$$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|^3}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
If we now compute the divergence of \eqref{1}
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\vec{E}&=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|^3}\right)=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\cdot4\pi\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r_i})= \\
&=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\cdot\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r_i})=:\frac{\rho(\vec{r})}{\varepsilon_0}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
what we have found is Gauss's law.

In electrostatics the electric field is the (opposite of the) gradient of a scalar function, it easy to see that the potential associated (up to an additive constant) to \eqref{1} is
$$\varphi(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{q_i}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|}\tag{3}\label{3}$$
In fact
$$-\nabla\varphi(\vec{r})=-\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^n\nabla\frac{q_i}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|^3}\tag{4}\label{4}=\vec{E}(\vec{r})$$
Combining \eqref{2} and \eqref{4} yields
$$\frac{\rho(\vec{r})}{\varepsilon_0}=\nabla\cdot\vec{E}(\vec{r})=-\nabla\cdot\nabla\varphi(\vec{r})=-\nabla^2\varphi(\vec{r})\iff\nabla^2\varphi(\vec{r})=-\frac{\rho(\vec{r})}{\varepsilon_0}\tag{5}\label{5}$$
which is Poisson's equation.